# How do I stop name-mangling of my DLL's exported function?

Tags: c++, c, extern, name-mangling

I'm trying to create a DLL that exports a function called "GetName". I'd like other code to be able to call this function without having to know the mangled function name.

My header file looks like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#endif

EXPORT TCHAR * CALLBACK GetName();
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "PluginOne.h"

int WINAPI DllMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD fdwReason, PVOID pvReserved)
{
     return TRUE ;
}

EXPORT TCHAR * CALLBACK GetName()
{
    return TEXT("Test Name");
}
```

When I build, the DLL still exports the function with the name: "_GetName@0".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Small correction - for success resolving name by clinet

```
extern "C"
```

must be as on export side as on import.

extern "C" will reduce name of proc to: "_GetName".

More over you can force any name with help of section EXPORTS in .def file

Comment: Hey cool this is exactly almost what I need. Now what if I want it the other way around? I have C function, completely fine to be c++ member function (vtable, calling convention all done), but the compiler figures it's name should be mangled.

Comment: Yes, C and C++ use different name decoration rules. To do what you asking about you need create wrapper that will invoke C function from C++ class member

Comment: A .DEF file is the only way to disable name mangling. `extern "C"` will still use name decoration, just not as verbose as C++ needs to.

Answer (score 10):

This is normal for a DLL export with a `__stdcall` convention.  The `@N` [indicates the number of bytes that the function takes in its arguments](http://us.geocities.com/yongweiwu/stdcall.htm) -- in your case, zero.

Note that [the MSDN page on Exporting from a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8(VS.80).aspx) specifically says to "use the __stdcall calling convention" when using "the keyword __declspec(dllexport) in the function's definition".

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names), the only way to overcome the mangling of a `__stdcall` is to use:   

`#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:SomeFunction=_SomeFunction@@@23mangledstuff#@@@@")`

Comment: your first link is broken and the second points to a download

Answer (score 7):

the right answer is the following:

```
extern "C" int MyFunc(int param);
```

and

```
int MyFunc(int param);
```

is two declarations which uses different internal naming, first - is in C-style, second - in the C++ style.

internal naming required for build tools to determine which arguments function receives, what type returns etc, since C++ is more complicated (oop's, overloaded, virtual functions etc) - it uses more complicated naming. calling convention also affects both c and c++ namings.

both this styles of naming is applied when using __declspec(dllexport) in the same manner.

if you want to omit name mangling of exported routine, add a module definition file to your project, type in it (in this case you not required to declspec dllexport):

```
LIBRARY mylib
EXPORTS
  MyFunc
```

this will omit explicit name decoration (samples below).

```
_MyFunc (c style, __cdecl)
_MyFunc@4 (c style, __stdcall)
?MyFunc@@YAHH@Z (c++ style, __cdecl)
?MyFunc@@YGHH@Z (c++ style, __stdcall)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "-Wl,--kill-at" linker switch to disable name mangling.

For example, in Code::Blocks, in the custom linker settings, add:
-Wl,--kill-at