# Unmangling C++ DLL Function Names

Tags: c++, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop name-mangling of my DLL's exported function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467144/how-do-i-stop-name-mangling-of-my-dlls-exported-function)

I have a DLL that is written in C++.  The exported function names need to be unmangled.  For example, `int MyFunc( int Param1, int Param2 );` needs to appear to an outside application trying to call the library function simply as `MyFunc`.  However, when I look at it using Dependency Walker, it looks like `_MyFunc@8`.  This is how I have it declared in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI MyFunc( int Param1, int Param2 );
```

I thought the `extern "C"` would do the trick.  How do I get rid of the mangling?  Thanks.

Comment: A .def file should do the trick.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467144/how-do-i-stop-name-mangling-of-my-dlls-exported-function

Comment: also useful link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x7kb4e2f(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: The `WINAPI` macro is in my code.  I forgot to add it in the the sample code that I posted.  It is there now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ways to get rid of mangling: (assuming MSVC is the build environment)

Export via a .DEF file.

Export as extern "C" ensuring that the __cdecl calling convention is used. __stdcall prepends the _ and postpends the @ on dll exported functions even when extern "C" is used.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl MyFunc(int Param1, int Param2);
```

Export using a #pragma directive. You need to pass the fully mangled name on the other side of this. `__FUNCDNAME__` is a useful directive to put in a macro in a function to list its decorated name,

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:MyFunc=_MyFunc@8");
```

Comment: Does `extern "C"` ensure that the `__cdecl` calling convention is used, or are those two separate things?

Comment: extern "C" merely ensures that the symbol is compatible with C code. __cdecl and __stdcall are separate directives that can be applied to fully decorated c++ functions

Comment: Should the pragma go immediately before the function declaration?

Comment: The pragma solution did the trick.  Not the cleanest way to do it, as it leaves the mangled artifacts in the DLL.  However, for my particular situation this is simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

The leading underscore and `@8` suffix are not from C++ name mangling, but rather denote *stdcall* calling convention, as is normal for *dllexport*.

Comment: Okay.  How do I get rid of them?

Comment: You change your calling convention to one that does not do such mangling.

Comment: If you use *cdecl* calling convention, these will go away, however your application needs to be aware of that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `WINAPI` macro (which translates to `__stdcall`) is required to maintain compatibility with other applications that are already deployed.

Comment: This sounds to me like the new application is unaware that this is a *stdcall* function, otherwise it'd refer to the decorated name (or are you resolving the name explicitly?).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you did not put `extern "C"` declspec on the function definition, you only put it on the declaration.

Comment: It is on both the declaration and the definition.

Answer (score 0):

On the header (**.h**), define it as:

```
extern "C" 
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MyFunc( int Param1, int Param2 );
}
```

Then, on the implementation (**.cpp**) of the function:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MyFunc( int Param1, int Param2 )
  {
     // ... code ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It has to be done using brackets?  Declaring `extern "C"` incline does not do the same thing?

Comment: @Jim You are right, you don't need brackets. I just put it for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

On Gnu systems there is **c++filt**

Comment: And on Windows it's `undname`. But the question's about stopping the mangling not decoding it.