# Using dumbin /exports of static library to write header file

Tags: c++, static-linking, dumpbin

## I have a static library (.lib file)

I would like to statically link and utilize in my program.  I don't have the source code, however, so I would need to write the header file myself.

**Here is the result of my dumbin /exports**

> File Type: LIBRARY
>
> ```
> Exports
>
>  ordinal    name
>
>       ?about@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall about(void))
>       ?barcode@@YGHPAD00000000@Z (int __stdcall barcode(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *))
>       ?clearbuffer@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall clearbuffer(void))
>       ?closeport@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall closeport(void))
>       ?downloadpcx@@YGHPAD0@Z (int __stdcall downloadpcx(char *,char *))
>       ?formfeed@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall formfeed(void))
>       ?nobackfeed@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall nobackfeed(void))
>       ?openport@@YGHPAD@Z (int __stdcall openport(char *))
>       ?printerfont@@YGHPAD000000@Z (int __stdcall printerfont(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *))
>       ?printlabel@@YGHPAD0@Z (int __stdcall printlabel(char *,char *))
>       ?sendcommand@@YGHPAD@Z (int __stdcall sendcommand(char *))
>       ?setup@@YGHPAD000000@Z (int __stdcall setup(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *))
>       ?usbportqueryprinter@@YGHXZ (int __stdcall usbportqueryprinter(void))
>       ?usbportwrite@@YGHPAD@Z (int __stdcall usbportwrite(char *))
>       ?windowsfont@@YGHHHHHHHPAD0@Z (int __stdcall windowsfont(int,int,int,int,int,int,char *,char *))
>       ?windowsfontU@@YGHHHHHHHPAD0@Z (int __stdcall windowsfontU(int,int,int,int,int,int,char *,char *))
> ```

I tried to write a header file so I could use those functions (showing one):

```
int __stdcall openport(char *printername);
```

I have statically linked the library to my program, and tried to call the function `openport`, but I get an `undefined reference to openport(char*)@4`.

Does anybody know how to write this so this will link properly?  (Or is this even a good idea?)

**Edit**

I also ran `undname ?openport@@YGHPAD@Z`, which returned:

> Undecoration of :- "?openport@@YGHPAD@Z"
>
> is :- "int __stdcall openport(char *)"

Which may mean I just can't link properly.

Comment: something to do with the name mingling. is your code in C++? check this url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467144/how-do-i-stop-name-mangling-of-my-dlls-exported-function

Comment: Very hard to believe that linker error message actually looks like that, it ought to complain about _openport@4.  Yeah, the @4 postfix sure looks like you are using a C compiler instead of the required C++ compiler.  The straw that breaks the camel's back is the .lib file you need to keep the linker happy when it needs to resolve ?openport@@YGHPAD@Z.  You can normally generate a .lib from a .def file with lib.exe but it doesn't like symbols that contain @.  LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress is your painful fallback.