# Why am I getting a "Unable to find an entry point named 'SquareRoot' in DLL" message?

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, pinvoke, unmanaged

I am having trouble calling a C++ function from dll in VB.net project. I have tried with the simple examples shown below

**For C++ dll**

```
#include <cmath>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double SquareRoot(double value)
{
    return pow(value, 0.5);
}
```

I build the dll and copy it to the VB.net folder

**For VB.net project**

```
Module Module1
    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("DLL_Test.dll")> _
    Private Function SquareRoot(ByVal value As Double) As Double

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        MsgBox(SquareRoot(2))
    End Sub

End Module
```

I keep getting `Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'SquareRoot' in DLL 'DLL_Test.dll'`. When I run `dumpbin.exe` on `DLL_Test.dll` I get the following

```
File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

I am not sure what I am missing, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use `/exports` when you ran `dumpbin` ?

Comment: Also, the global `pow` function comes from `<math.h>`.  `<cmath>` provides `std::pow` instead.

Comment: Sounds like you might be running into name mangling on the C++ side. You can use Dependency Walker(http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the actual function name that the C++ code is exporting.   Also, this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467144/how-do-i-stop-name-mangling-of-my-dlls-exported-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name mangling.  `extern "C"` doesn't turn it off, it just changes the rules.

You also have a calling convention mismatch.

You can solve both at once via `__stdcall` keyword on the C++ function.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have changed `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double SquareRoot(double value)` to `double __stdcall SquareRoot(double value)` but I am still getting the same error

Comment: I meant to combine that with the existing code, not take away the old annotations.

Comment: I am not sure I am following, sorry it has been a long day :)

Comment: `__stdcall` on the C++ side will still lead to a decorate name. Simplest is `__cdecl` on both sides to avoid decoration.